# How to lock scrolling of main page when opening iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

On my website, when a link is clicked an iframe popup opens and loads the link.
I want the user to be able to scroll in the iframe, but the problem is when I scroll all the way down in the iframe it starts to scroll the main page underneath the iframe.

Basically, when the iframe is open, I want the page underneath locked with respect to scrolling.

Is this possible?

Comment: It would be helpful if you add some [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user overflow property, the overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.

- visible:     The overflow is not clipped. It renders outside the element's box. This is default....
- hidden:  The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible...
- scroll:  The overflow is clipped, but a scroll-bar is added to see the rest of the content....
- auto: If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content...
- inherit:     Specifies that the value of the overflow property should be inherited from the parent element...

Answer (score 1):

When you wan't to lock the parent window set **`style.overflow`** for **`html`** and **`body`** in the parent-document to **`hidden`**